# Angularjs: Check to push and unchecked to splice id from array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, push, splice

I have a table fetched from php script. given below code work perfectly when i tick the box it push ids successfully but while splice it didn't work well.
it splice array too when i tick and untick only single row. but when i select  multiple rows it push again and again even when i untick. please check the code.

```js
$scope.exampleArray = [];
  $scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
  // get the input value
 /* var inputVal = id;*/
  var index = $scope.exampleArray.indexOf(id);
  if( index ){
   $scope.exampleArray.push(id);
  }else { $scope.exampleArray.splice(index, 1);  }
   $scope.deleteBulk = function(){

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + $scope.exampleArray.length + " record(s))?")){
     $http.post('http://localhost/angular-code-crud/index.php/user/bulk_delete_user',
          {'id':$scope.exampleArray}).success(function(){
              $scope.displayUsers();
          });
       }
     };  
  };
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th ng-click="sort('name')">Name
   <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
   <th ng-click="sort('gender')">Gender<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='gender'" ng-class="{' glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,' glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
   <th ng-click="sort('email')">Email<span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='email'" ng-class="{' glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,' glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span></th>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>Phone</th>
   <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <!-- <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchUser | orderBy:sortKey:reverse | filter:paginate"> -->
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:searchUser " >
 
  <td><!-- <input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteBulk(user.id)" ng-true-value="{{user.id}}" ng-checked="master" checklist-model="user.id" checklist-value="{{user.id}}">{{ user.id }} -->
   <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="arrExample" ng-model="arrInput" ng-change='pushInArray(user.id)' >
    </label>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.address }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
  <td>
   <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateData(user.id, user.name, user.gender, user.email, user.address, user.phone)">Edit <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteData(user.id)">Delete <i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found where was bug.

```js
$scope.exampleArray = [];
  $scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
  // get the input value
 /* var inputVal = id;*/
  //$scope.exampleArray.push(id);
  var index = $scope.exampleArray.indexOf(id);
   console.log(index);
  if(index === -1 ){ //this is where i have bug. match the condition with -1
   $scope.exampleArray.push(id); 
  } else { $scope.exampleArray.splice(index, 1);}
   $scope.deleteBulk = function(){

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete " + $scope.exampleArray.length + " record(s))?")){
     $http.post('http://localhost/angular-code-crud/index.php/user/bulk_delete_user',
          {'id':$scope.exampleArray}).success(function(){
              $scope.displayUsers();
          });
       }
     };  
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

JS :

```
$scope.pushInArray = function(data) {
    var index = $scope.exampleArray.indexOf(data.id);
    if(data.checked) {
        if( index === -1 ) {
            $scope.exampleArray.push(data.id);
        }
    } else {
        $scope.exampleArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

HTML : change `input type="checkbox"` line to below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="arrExample" ng-model="user.checked" ng-change='pushInArray(user)' >
```

Answer (score 0):

change condition index

```
 $scope.pushInArray = function (id) {
        var index = $scope.exampleArray.indexOf(id);
        if (index <= -1) {
            $scope.exampleArray.push(id);
        } else
            $scope.exampleArray.splice(index, 1);
        };
    };
```